# Laravel 4 - update data pivot table

Tags: database, laravel-4, eloquent, updates, pivot-table

I have an 'Edit page' with a form, where I want to update some data.

My Models:

Actividad.php:

```
 public function materials()
        {       
            return $this->belongsToMany('Material', 'actividad_material')->withTimestamps();

        }
```

And Material.php:

```
public function actividads()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Actividad', 'actividad_material')->withTimestamps();
}
```

My code (Controller):

```
public function update($id)
{
    $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');

    $v = Validator::make($input, Actividad::$rules);
    // return 'Hala';
    if($v->passes())
    {

        $actividad = Actividad::find($id);
        $material_id = Input::get('material_id');           
        $actividad->materials()->sync($material_id);

        Actividad::find($id)->update($input);

        // return 'hola';
        return Redirect::route('actividads.index');
    }

    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($v);
}
```

The application gives me an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'material_id' in 'field list' (SQL: update `actividads` set `updated_at` = 2014-07-20 16:20:03, `material_id` = 1 where `id` = 16)

I suppose it is because it's looking for a column in my 'actividads' that doesn't already exist! Maybe I have to change `$input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');`... I think I'm telling with that, that every inputs in the form are in my 'Actividad', and this is not true. I need to update my pivot table with 'material_id'.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: How have you defined the relations in your models? It doesn't look like Laravel thinks you are using a pivot table.

Comment: Edited question with relations.

Comment: Oh, I missed the line where you update before you sync, so I thought the sync was giving the error. Yeah, looks like you're passing a ``material_id => 1`` to the update. Also looks like the update isn't really doing anything, do you even need it?

Comment: I've changed the order and now I've done first my 'sync' and then, the 'update'. Now, the error that I have is: "Call to a member function materials() on a non-object ". Question edited to show the changes.

Comment: You're trying to use ``$actividad``, but you haven't actually set it when you try to access it.

Comment: I've declared `$actividad = Actividad::find($id);` and I have the next error message: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::formatSyncList() must be of the type array, string given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/webs/lara4/edu1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php on line 578 and defined`

Comment: So give it an array then? :) ``$actividad->materials()->sync([$material_id]);``

Comment: Then, I got the same first error message! :S

Comment: Maybe I have to do something to pass through my `$input` only the inputs I want to update in the 'Actividad' table (all of them but material_id)...

Comment: You moved your update method, which wasn't working, to after the sync. So when we got the sync method working, it moved on to update and failed again. Since you only pass material_id to your update, why do you even have that row? The sync method takes care of the material_id updating for you.

Comment: Yes, that seems likely. Only put in your ``$input`` what you actually need to update.